# Eloquent связи в Laravel

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

Доброго времени суток. 
Подскажите, возможно ли прописать связь hasMany сразу к двум таблицам, причем ко второй таблице через первую. Например есть категории, есть рубрики этой категории, в рубриках располагаются записи. Знаю точно что с помощью belongsTo такое возможно таким куском кода: (связь из модели Post.php)

```
public function partition()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Rubric::class, 'parent_id', 'id')->getResults()
        ->belongsTo(Partition::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

Возможно ли подобным образом прописать связи hasMany, что то вроде такого: (Partition.php)

```
public function posts() {
    return self::hasMany(Rubric::class, 'parent_id', 'id')->getResults()
        ->hasMany(Post::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

Связь из Post.php работает, а вот в Partition.php нет, пишет что связь не найдена. Если убрать из этой функции последний hasMany и getResults, т.е. оставить только:

```
public function partition()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Rubric::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

То ошибки, что связь не найдена нету, но соответственно по такой связи я получаю рубрики раздела, а нужно записи в рубрике раздела.

Возможно я что-то делаю не так, или так связь работать не будет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Порылся еще раз в документации ларавель, видимо сперва невнимательно просмотрел страницу отношений. Если кому то будет нужно, решение такое:

```
public function posts() {
    return self::hasManyThrough(Post::class,Rubric::class, 'parent_id', 'parent_id', 'id', 'parent_id');
}
```